# How do I convert ASEC files to APK?

Tags: apk

Is there anyone that knows how I can convert ASEC files **to** **APK**?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to this [question/answer](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/1876/analyzing-encrypted-android-apps-asec), the .asec files are actually dm-crypt containers which can be mounted, and contain the unencrypted .apk. The keys are stored in `/data/misc/systemkeys/AppsOnSD.sks`.

The mounting process depends on the tools available, but it can be as simple as running (on Linux) `losetup /dev/loop0 /path/to/file && cryptSetup open --type luks -d /path/to/keyfile /dev/loop0 asecmount && mount -t ext4 /dev/mapper/asecmount /your/mountpoint` to mount and `umount /your/mountpoint && cryptsetup close asecmount && losetup -d /dev/loop0`.

You can also access the contents of the .asec file from `/mnt/asec/[app-id]/` if you have it already mounted on your device.